# QtCreator works very slow with ROS on Ubuntu 16 (14 OK)

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Anybody has solution for this problem?

When I moved to Ubuntu 16 and ROS Kinetic from 14 and Indigo, I couldn't use QtCreator because of long latencies of GUI, it is very slow, when using autocompletion, going to definitions, refactoring, copying and so on.

This is common issue on two my computers and for my teammate.

For Ubuntu 14 and ROS Indigo it worked perfect.

Also it works OK for non-ROS projects.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262165/qtcreator-works-very-slow-with-ros-on-ubuntu-16-(14-ok)/) by [Rr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2748/rr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems be not strictly related to ROS and is a known (but apparently not yet fixed) issue. See for instance [this bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1577213). It appears two possible workarounds are

- Install QtCreator from a PPA (I think [this one](https://launchpad.net/%7Eadrozdoff/+archive/ubuntu/qtcreator-git) is meant in the bug report I linked above).
- Install QtCreator using the [installer script from the Qt website](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-9).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2748/rr/) on 2017-05-19**:
Thank you!

I am not alone)

Installed 4.2.2 from website and done configuration according http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#QtCreator
Seems that is really fixed for now (I tried few month ago, when it wasn't help).